# Keeping things DRY in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I've done a couple of projects with React in the last year and I've switched to Vue for my current one, attracted by its greater simplicity, less verbose nature and the fact that you don't have to transpile your code to work, so it's easier to get going with and more flexible (well, to be accurate you don't *have to* transpile with React either, there's no need to use JSX, but it loses one of its great benefits if you don't).

Anyway, one of the things I'm missing from React (and I'm sure it's just ignorance of the Vue way which is my problem) is a way of reusing a fragment of code to avoid repeating myself in templates. The specific situation which prompted this question was a template where I have a custom input element like this:

```
<input ref="input" :id='name' :name='name' :type='fieldType' class='form-control' :value="value" :readonly="readonly" :disabled="disabled" @input="handleInput"/>
```

In certain situations I'd want to wrap it in a div, otherwise I'd want to use it as is. With React, I'd simply store it in a variable, something like this:

```
var inp=( <input ref="input" :id='name' :name='name' :type='fieldType' class='form-control' :value="value" :readonly="readonly" :disabled="disabled"
                               @input="handleInput"/>);
```

Then I could do something like the following:

```
var myInput;
if(divSituation){
  myInput=(<div>{inp}</div>);
} else {
  myInput=inp;
}
```

Then I could use the myInput var. The Vue logic doesn't seem to allow this, though. Unless, of course, using JSX within Vue would allow me to do the very same thing? I currently have for this in Vue something like the following, which offends me:

```
<template v-if="divSituation">
  <div><input ref="input" :id='name' :name='name' :type='fieldType' class='form-control' :value="value" :readonly="readonly" :disabled="disabled" @input="handleInput"/></div>
</template>
<template v-else>
  <input ref="input" :id='name' :name='name' :type='fieldType' class='form-control' :value="value" :readonly="readonly" :disabled="disabled" @input="handleInput"/
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create vue [components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html) for re-usable components, which can be used as par requirement.

You can find an example of re-usable input component in [vue docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Form-Input-Components-using-Custom-Events):

```
<currency-input v-model="price"></currency-input>
```

and you can write that as re-usable component like following:

```
Vue.component('currency-input', {
  template: '\
    <span>\
      $\
      <input\
        ref="input"\
        v-bind:value="value"\
        v-on:input="updateValue($event.target.value)"\
      >\
    </span>\
  ',
  props: ['value'],
  methods: {
    // Instead of updating the value directly, this
    // method is used to format and place constraints
    // on the input's value
    updateValue: function (value) {
      var formattedValue = value
        // Remove whitespace on either side
        .trim()
        // Shorten to 2 decimal places
        .slice(0, value.indexOf('.') + 3)
      // If the value was not already normalized,
      // manually override it to conform
      if (formattedValue !== value) {
        this.$refs.input.value = formattedValue
      }
      // Emit the number value through the input event
      this.$emit('input', Number(formattedValue))
    }
  }
})
```

You can add more props for readonly, disabled, etc.

You can also have a look at custom input elements of [element-ui](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input) and it's [code](https://github.com/ElemeFE/element/blob/db666dfb4b9eb294880914ac377852a38b8a2851/packages/input/src/input.vue#L70).

---

Given the example you have given, You can use [v-html](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) more efficiently. with `v-html`, you can pass a HTML string which will be rendered as HTML. However Note: **the contents are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates.**

You can have a computed property, which will return HTML string as par your variable: `divSituation`, like following:

```
var data = {
    templateInput: '<input ref="input" :id="name" :name="name" :type="fieldType" class="form-control" :value="value" :readonly="readonly" :disabled="disabled"   @input="handleInput"/>',
    divSituation: true,
    myInput: ''
}

var demo = new Vue({
    el: '#demo',
    data: function(){
        return data
    },
    computed: {
       getMyInput: function(){
          if(this.divSituation){
              return this.templateInput
          }
          else{
              return '<div>' + this.templateInput + '</div>' 
          }
       }
    }
})
```

Now you can just render `myInput` in HTML using `v-html` like this:

```
<div id="demo">
  <div v-html="getMyInput">
  </div>
</div>
```

check out working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goz38g6x/).

Comment: The doc says the `v-html` template `are inserted as plain HTML - they will not be compiled as Vue templates`, so we may need to move the input to vue's template and define `<div></div>` like `prefix = '<div>'` `suffix = '</div>'`?

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this works. The input needs to be reactive - this just appears to output some HTML to the page which isn't handled by Vue. Or have I misunderstood something? Incidentally, I think render functions would probably meet my requirements nicely, if I could get my head around how to use them :)

Comment: @JohnMoore If you want to make the input reactive, you can create custom component for it, see the updated answer.

Comment: @JohnMoore Other libraries also create their custom input elements, which are re-used, see input element of [element-ui](http://element.eleme.io/#/en-US/component/input).